# How to elegantly check the existence of an object/instance/variable and simultaneously assign it to variable if it exists in python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to populate a database and often I need to check if a orm object exists in a database before processing. This may be an unconventional question, but I found myself encountering this pattern often:

```
my_object = session.query(SomeObject).filter(some_fiter).first()
if my_object: # Mostly in databases...
    # Juchee it exists
    # process
else:
    # It does not exist. :-(
    my_object = SomeObject()
    # process
```

What I am **dreaming** of would be something like:

```
if my_object = session.query(someObject).blabla.first():
    # if my_object is None this scope is left alone
    # if my_object is not None I can work with my_object here...
```

I know, that this syntax is wrong, but I wanted to explain, what I mean by this example. Any equivalent way would make me happy.

Is there an elegant python approach for this pattern? This question aims not only at SQLAlchemy, but to each equivalent scenario.

*closing my eyes hitting "Post your question" and waiting for the smart people and pythonistas by heart to hunt me down for asking something mayhaps inappropriate* ;-)

Comment: Explicit is always better than implicit, says Python... and we get this. It frustrated me at first too. So inelegant. Oh well.

Comment: According to [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), we'll have this in Python 3.8 in the form `if my_object := session.query(...):` which is pretty much exactly what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You want to execute a Exist query to be efficient

```
(ret, ), = Session.query(exists().where(SomeObject.field==value))
```

Mike Bayer explain it in his blog post:
http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2008/09/09/selecting-booleans/

You can use scalar if you don't want to have a tuple as result:

```
ret = Session.query(exists().where(SomeObject.field==value)).scalar()
```

Comment: Don't forget to import exists(): `from sqlalchemy import exists`

Comment: How can I check for more than one field?  i.e. in the 'where' call something like 'Someobject.field1==value1 and Someobject.field2==value2'

Comment: I found it. `ret = Session.query(exists().where(and_(Someobject.field1 == value1, Someobject.field2 == value2)))`

Comment: Is there a way to get the data using a dynamic field? For eg.
   
     field_name = 'id' or field_name = 'email'
     ret = Session.query(exists().where(SomeObject[field_name]==value)).scalar()

Comment: To make it more generic and not specifying type it can be modified into: `session.query(exists().where(type(my_object).id == my_object.id)).scalar()`

Answer (score 26):

This has been asked a long time ago but for future visitors a more concise way to check is

```
 if session.query(model).filter(some_filter).count():
     # do stuff
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what he asked for.

Comment: `count()` may be concise, but it's also inefficient -- more expensive to check *how many* things match filter X than to check if *any* things match filter X; for the "exists" check, one can declare success when the first match is found, rather than continuing to look for more.

Comment: what is model and what is some_filter?

Comment: Model is whatever model you are querying for and filter is whatever filter you want to filter the query by.

Answer (score 14):

wrap it on a function (shamelessly stolen from django get_or_create, this doesnt return a tuple though)

```
get_or_create(model, **kwargs):
    try:
        # basically check the obj from the db, this syntax might be wrong
        object = session.query(model).filter(**kwargs).first()
        return object
    except DoesNotExistException: # or whatever error/exception it is on SQLA
        object = model()
        # do it here if you want to save the obj to the db
        return object
```

that's it. to use it:

```
obj = get_or_create(SomeObject, filters)
```

change the `**kwargs` to a simple argument (like some_filters) if you want

**try to wrap something you often use (wrap them to functions or classes)**

thats only pseudo code, there might be syntax error.

EDIT: emphasize

Comment: bonus point: try make your function tells you, whether the object it gives you is from the db or newly created (the hint is already there: see django's get_or_create)

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not all one step, but is this acceptable?

```
my_object = session.query(SomeObject).filter(some_filter).first()
if my_object is None:
    my_object = SomeObject()
#process
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import has_identity

my_object = session.query(SomeObject).get(id) or SomeObject()
# Processing...

# Check if the object exists in the database
if not has_identity(my_object):
    session.add(my_object)

session.commit()
```

.get() can be replaced with a filter() + first() if needed

Answer (score 2):

```
if DBSession.query(ObjectType).filter(ObjectType.some_parametter == "This").first() is None:
```

This is an efficient one line way of checking whether a record exists. It is efficient because it only grabs the first object, and it can be on one line because first() returns None when there are no matching records. Hope that helps!

Comment: i agree. this is super clean and efficient without having to use extra resources on a try/exception block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
sth = session.query.filter_by().first()
if sth is None:
    ....
else:
    ....
```

I have tested it.It works well.

Answer (score 1):

Some nice suggestions here. How about using the NoResultFound exception?

```
try:
    existing = dbsession.query(SomeObject).filter_by(value=value).one()
    return existing
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
    obj = SomeObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to check the existence of an object using SQLalchemy.

```
def exists(obj, **kwargs):
    """" if obj filtered by kwargs exist return it otherwise return None
        obj : is the sql alchemy model object which existence is being checked here.
        **kwargs : (username = user_name, email=user_email)
    """
    db_obj = obj.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if db_obj is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```