# How to check if value is already exist in database (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to check if unique element is already present in postgresdb. 
My method in views.py is

```
def bestfriend(username):
    print username
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    if user == None:
        flash('bestfriend not found.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    print user
    u = g.user.friend(user)
    #print bestfriend.id
    if u is None:
        #flash('Cannot be friend %(username)s.', username = username)
        return redirect(url_for('user', username = username))
    if db.session.query(bestfriend).filter(bestfriend.id==u.id).first():
        flash('Already Exist') 
        return redirect(url_for('index'))   
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your bestfriend has been added.')
    return redirect(url_for('user', username = username))
```

My model.py is

```
bestfriend= db.Table('bestfriend',

    db.Column('id',db.Integer, primary_key = True),
    db.Column('friendid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)


class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column('username', db.String(20), unique=True , index=True)
    password = db.Column('password' , db.String(10))
    email = db.Column('email',db.String(50),unique=True , index=True)
    registered_on = db.Column('registered_on' , db.DateTime)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')
    followed = db.relationship('Users', 
        secondary = followers, 
        primaryjoin = (followers.c.follower_id == id), 
        secondaryjoin = (followers.c.followed_id == id), 
        backref = db.backref('followers', lazy = 'dynamic'), 
        lazy = 'dynamic')
    bestfriends = db.relationship('Users',
        secondary = bestfriend, 
        primaryjoin = (bestfriend.c.friendid == id), 
        secondaryjoin = (bestfriend.c.id == id), 
        backref = db.backref('bestfriend', lazy = 'dynamic'), 
        lazy = 'dynamic')
```

I am able to insert value in database table bestfriend

```
Table "public.bestfriend"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 id       | integer | not null
 friendid | integer | 
Indexes:
    "bestfriend_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "bestfriend_friendid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (friendid) REFERENCES users(id)
```

but after insertion, I have to check if record is already present, using this line

```
if db.session.query(bestfriend).filter(bestfriend.id==u.id).first():
```

I am not sure about this statement. I have already tried similar solutions [How to elegantly check the existence of an object/instance/variable and simultaneously assign it to variable if it exists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587879/how-to-elegantly-check-the-existence-of-an-object-instance-variable-and-simultan)     but it didn't worked for me.

I didn't receive any reply so adding some more info. I just want to check if id = 8 is already present in bestfriend table

```
app=> select * from bestfriend;
 id | friendid 
----+----------
  8 |       11
```

Answer (score 4):

Your statement does not work because `bestfriend` is a Table, not a mapped class. To fix the *typo*, just add `c.` to the query:

```
exists = db.session.query(bestfriend).filter(bestfriend.c.id==u.id).first()
```

Given that your relationship is defined as dynamic, you can do it easier with the following:

```
exists = user.bestfriends.filter(Users.id == u.id).one()
```

---

*Side remark: Note that your `bestfriend` table is not structured correctly to allow many-to-many relationship. In order to do that, please change the definition of the table as per below:*

```
bestfriend = db.Table('bestfriend',
    db.Column('id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key = True),
    db.Column('friendid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key = True)
)
```

*Another remark: I do not understand the code flow: you add a friend at step `u = g.user.friend(user)`, but later check if it exists. Shall logic not be reversed?*

Comment: Can you explain how it should be structured? I had already tried making it a class but solution was not working for me.

Comment: For your Another remark: friend and bestfriend are two different functionality.A person can be a friend but may not be bestfriend. For Side Remark: Are you asking me 'id' and 'friendid'  to create both as primary key?  Also both primary key refer to same foreign key in Users table with  'id'

Comment: I assumed this is the case. Just read [Many-to-Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) of the documentation. Regarding primary_key: if you have it only on one column, it must be unique. This means that each User can have only one bestfriend. If this is the case, then your model is fine, but in this case I would model it differently without any separate table. Shall this not be the case, you should ensure that there is a unique constraint covering both columns (id, friendid). Making them both part of primary key is one way of doing that.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to find if a record exists in a table, You can do it like this:

```
select 1 from table_name;
```

or better

```
select 1 from table_name where rownum=1;
```

The image below shows the query with output.

If there are any data, it will return 1 in the column.

[image]