# flask sqlalchemy check if object exist in db

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, exists

I have a Flask application which uses Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a database.

I need to check if row with `name='reza'` exists...

I think I can use `Any()`, `Exists()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
user = User.query.filter_by(name='reza').count()
if count > 0:
    print 'user exists'
```

Comment: count() is a super-inefficient way of checking the existence of an object.
There is an exist() function in SQLAlchemy with this purpose. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16003360/1674908

Comment: @Hamlett You are correct, this is the best way to do it - I wasn't aware of this function at the time.